# Составить правильный запрос Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем доброго. Есть следующий запрос:

```
$chat_list = ChatModel::where('creator', session()->get('id'))
               ->orWhere('reciever', session()->get('id'))
               ->get();
```

Получаем список всех сообщений в чате, нужно сгрупировать по отдельным чатам с пользователями. Уже голову изломал как построить запрос, из моих идей - добавлять к чату идентификатор. Прошу Вашей помощи.

Comment: Вы хотите сгруппировать всё в одном запросе и получить список из всех строк или отдельные массивы по каждому чату? И приведите структуру таблиц в БД, а то это будет пальцем в небо.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Вы правы. Я хочу всё сгрупировать в одном запросе. Структура таблицы следующая: `id(int primary key), creator(int), reciever(int), text(text), created_at(datetime)`. Думал над добавлением идентификатора чата, что-бы потом использовать метод `groupBy`

Answer (score 0):

Ну может подойти что-то наподобие этого.
Только нужно учесть что если в БД используется ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, то при добавлении полей в select их так же нужно будет добавлять в groupBy

```
    ChatModel::where('creator', session()->get('id'))
        ->orWhere('reciever', session()->get('id'))
        ->selectRaw('CASE creator > reciever THEN CONCAT(creator, "-", reciever) ELSE CONCAT(reciever, "-", creator) as user_pair')
        ->groupBy('user_pair')
        ->get();
```